Systemd shutdown hanging for 90 seconds due to luks/btrfs
Ever since I got my luks w/ BTRFS raid1 between my two NVMe drives on Debian 12, the shutdown process has taken way too long, about a minute and a half.
I had to get a video of the shutdown screen before it powers off, which led me to the culprit of the dm/crypt not being un-mounted.
I realize that "/" being on the unlocked BTRFS file systems must complicate the umounting process during shutdown, but waiting this long cannot be the only way.
I wouldn't care too much, as other posts about this issue suggest, except that waiting this long for a shutdown is annoying, and waiting this long for a reboot is frustrating.
It's also a laptop, so waiting this amount of time before putting it away in my bag is a problem.
I am guessing that this is supposed to happen, I wouldn't think people with LUKS and BTRFS are trulying waiting this long for reboot/shutdown??

In my particular disk setup, is there any risk in these devices not being umounted properly?
Is there any way to remove the huge delay in shutdown? I attempted to change systemd's watchdog timer to 3 seconds, but it did not affect the shutdown time.
Why doesn't systemd handle this already? On a normal system, "/" would be on an EXT4 filesystem that would also need to be umounted at shutdown?

lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1         259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1     259:2    0   949M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2     259:3    0 930.6G  0 part
  └─crypt_nvme0 254:0    0 930.6G  0 crypt /
nvme1n1         259:1    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1     259:4    0   949M  0 part
└─nvme1n1p2     259:5    0 930.6G  0 part
  └─crypt_nvme1 254:1    0 930.6G  0 crypt

cat /etc/fstab
# MAIN
# Primary efi partition - secondary below
UUID=A490-28B5                            /boot/efi             vfat    umask=0077,noexec,nodev,nosuid  0       1

# BTRFS RAID 1 (UUID applies to both disks)
UUID=15767954-1ec3-44aa-b1e3-b890ca937277 /             btrfs   defaults,subvol=@,ssd,noatime,space_cache=v2,commit=120,compress=zstd 0 0

cat /etc/crypttab
crypt_nvme0 UUID=63780057-f91e-426d-9be3-84383fd9b534 none luks
crypt_nvme1 UUID=c434a425-6552-4036-ae34-4f8c1c728d9a none luks

journald logs before next boot:
Nov 17 15:35:36 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:36 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5094]: Device crypt_nvme0 is still in use.
Nov 17 15:35:36 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5094]: Failed to deactivate: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:36 debian systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@crypt_nvme0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 17 15:35:36 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:37 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:37 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:37 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:37 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:37 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:38 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:38 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:38 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:38 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:38 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:39 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:39 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:39 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:39 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:39 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:40 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:40 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:40 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:40 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:40 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: device-mapper: remove ioctl on crypt_nvme1  failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: Device crypt_nvme1 is still in use.
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian systemd-cryptsetup[5080]: Failed to deactivate: Device or resource busy
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@crypt_nvme1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 17 15:35:41 debian kernel: watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!

Last messages before power off:
systemd-shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-1: Device or resource busy
systemd-shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-0: Device or resource busy
watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
sstemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize DM devices, ignoring.

ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Nov 17 15:36 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 17 15:36 crypt_nvme0 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 17 15:36 crypt_nvme1 -> ../dm-1

After reboot systemd crypt services:
● blockdev@dev-mapper-crypt_nvme0.target - Block Device Preparation for /dev/mapper/crypt_nvme0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/blockdev@.target; static)
     Active: active since Sun 2024-11-17 15:36:35 PST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

● systemd-cryptsetup@crypt_nvme1.service - Cryptography Setup for crypt_nvme1
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/crypttab; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2024-11-17 15:36:35 PST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:crypttab(5)
             man:systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8)
             man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
    Process: 896 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach crypt_nvme1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/c434a425-6552-4036-ae34-4f8c1c728d9a none luks (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 896 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 5ms

Nov 17 15:36:35 debian systemd-cryptsetup[896]: Volume crypt_nvme1 already active.

● system-systemd\x2dcryptsetup.slice - Cryptsetup Units Slice
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/system-systemd\x2dcryptsetup.slice; static)
     Active: active since Sun 2024-11-17 15:36:34 PST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
      Tasks: 0
     Memory: 828.0K
        CPU: 10ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-systemd\x2dcryptsetup.slice

Nov 17 15:36:35 debian systemd-cryptsetup[896]: Volume crypt_nvme1 already active.
Nov 17 15:36:35 debian systemd-cryptsetup[895]: Volume crypt_nvme0 already active.
Notice: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.

● systemd-cryptsetup@crypt_nvme0.service - Cryptography Setup for crypt_nvme0
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/crypttab; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2024-11-17 15:36:35 PST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:crypttab(5)
             man:systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8)
             man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
    Process: 895 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach crypt_nvme0 /dev/disk/by-uuid/63780057-f91e-426d-9be3-84383fd9b534 none luks (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 895 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 5ms

Nov 17 15:36:35 debian systemd-cryptsetup[895]: Volume crypt_nvme0 already active.

● cryptsetup.target - Local Encrypted Volumes
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cryptsetup.target; static)
     Active: active since Sun 2024-11-17 15:36:35 PST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

● blockdev@dev-mapper-crypt_nvme1.target - Block Device Preparation for /dev/mapper/crypt_nvme1
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/blockdev@.target; static)
     Active: active since Sun 2024-11-17 15:36:35 PST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17 15:36 15767954-1ec3-44aa-b1e3-b890ca937277 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 17 15:36 63780057-f91e-426d-9be3-84383fd9b534 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 17 15:36 A490-28B5 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 17 15:36 c434a425-6552-4036-ae34-4f8c1c728d9a -> ../../nvme1n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 17 15:36 D2D5-D83C -> ../../nvme1n1p1

mount | grep nvme
/dev/mapper/crypt_nvme0 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache=v2,commit=120,subvolid=256,subvol=/@)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)


You have your filesystem root (/) on your RAIDed drives. Shutdown needs /, but also needs to unmount your RAIDed drives. Thus the timeout. Check the documentation, it may be that "/ on RAID" is a disallowed configuration.

On Debian's own wiki https://wiki.debian.org/SoftwareRAID has a section on root filesystem on RAID (with mdraid). Unfortunately, does not mention setting it up to properly umount on shutdown.
